# I cannot save php.ini in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, permissions, filesystem, php

I want to change the  `upload_max_filesize = 2M` to `50M`, then I started edit on php.ini, but when try to save it, it displays error message below

> Could not create a backup file while saving /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
>
> gedit could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new one. You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, but if an error occurs while saving, you could lose the old copy of the file. Save anyway?

[image: cannot save php.ini]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are opening that file in a folder owned by root! Hence you need root access to that file. Type this code in the terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

When the file opens edit the file and you can save it normally by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: I have edited the answer. The root folder is /, the file is in another place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have permission when your text editor creates a backup file.

You can either

1. Run gedit using administrative permission.

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
   ```

   In this part gedit will create a backup file with root permission. A new file will be created with root as owner.

or

2. You can disable the gedit feature thats create backup copy before saving.

   Go to **Edit > Preferences > Editor**

   Uncheck **Create a backup copy of files before saving**

Answer (score 0):

By default the file is read-only and you need admin powers for this

```
sudo -H gedit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Now file will open in gedit and one can edit and save successfully. changes will be visible in you xamp local host info page only after you restart the servers.